# Anything like VisualSVN Server for Mercurial?

Tags: windows, svn, mercurial

VisualSVN server is a nice piece of software; particularly in that it uses the builtin Windows authentication mechanism on my server. I'd like to try to start using Mercurial though, and I'd like to keep the Windows authentication scheme.

Is there some way to set this kind of thing up using the tools available on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (in particular, IIS 7)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799187/dvcs-with-a-windows-central-repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using it within a LAN, you can just store your mercurial repo on a windows network share - no need for a server component.

If need it web-accessible, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799187/dvcs-with-a-windows-central-repository) Am linked to above seems to cover how to set up IIS.

If you're not adverse to paying, [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln) might be worth investigating, though I can't tell from the info on the site if they use Windows auth.

Comment: Wouldn't a windows share cause problems if multiple machines attempted to access the repo at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Excuse my necroposting, but I've just released an alpha version of [HgLab](http://hglabhq.com/), which is a purely managed Mercurial Server for Windows.

Comment: Does this "purely managed" server support Windows authentication?

Comment: @BillyONeal Not yet, but planned.

Comment: then how is it relevant to this question? Don't get me wrong, I'm all for putting in "advertising answers" where they're relevant, but the point of this question was asking about the authentication mechanism, and your solution doesn't yet do that,.

Comment: @BillyONeal ...and now it supports AD :)